# PHP SQLSRV driver fetches NULL as empty string

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, sqlsrv

We are currently moving our PHP project from Server A (PHP5, PDO_SQLSRV) to B (PHP7, SQLSRV).

Still stuck on Zend Framework 1. SQL server is on a different machine.

Whenever we select a field that has no value (in other word: NULL) in it, PHP is thinking it's an empty string.

so checking with `=== null` in PHP on an empty string is returning false.

So a code snippet like this would lead to an error, since the `decode` Method does not accept empty strings. This would be prevented if the if-Statement would be true.

```
<?php
    public function myMethod() {
        /**
            [...]
            Imagine some code here that fetches a single row/column with NULL in it
        */

        if($potentialJsonFromDbTable === null) {
            return '[]';
        }

        return Zend_Json::decode($potentialJsonFromDbTable);
    }
```

And since the project is large, we can't go through all spots that read from the table and change the code. Funny enough, that it works fine on the local virtual box my workmate provided me, where PHP7 and SQLSRV are installed with a connection to the same database, and usage of the same git branch.

Is there any configuration we need to set on the server itself? In the PHP-Code, we already have `SET ANSI_NULL ON` called everytime the pages are loaded.

EDIT: After experiment a bit more, it seems that Zend Framework's fetch methods `fetchCol` and `fetchOne` are the only ones that see anything that is null in the database table as null in PHP, whilst other fetch methods like `fetchRow` - which is in use right now (!) - are turning them into empty strings.

And also, this happens on varchar fields, while int fields are seen as null.

Edit 2: Now, as I went deeper into the source code, I found the following lines. Both are called when the field type is varchar.

```
$fieldResource = sqlsrv_get_field($this->_stmt,$count,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
$value = stream_get_contents($fieldResource);
```

Is there any workaround to let the code know that null is fine?

Comment: What is `PDO_SQL` (I assume it is `PDO_SQLSRV` - the PDO version of PHP Driver for SQL Server)?

Comment: @Zhorov Ugh, looks like I missed some letters there, editing/fixing now

Comment: Thanks. And (to make it clear), now you are using `SQLSRV`, which is a different version of the PHP Driver for SQL Server (not PDO)?

Comment: Indeed, not PDO anymore.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue (PHP 7.4.8 and PHP Driver for SQL Server 5.8.0+12928). The test case is simple - statement `SELECT NULL AS ReturnText` and `sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` for fetching the data. Probably a test case will help here. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, we are using the Zend Framework methods, like `$statement = $this->query($sql, $bind);` and `$result = $statement->fetch($fetchMode);`. Now I saw that we actually have 2 columns in the table that have NULL in their fields. Funny though, one of them is changed into an empty string, whilst the other one is known as NULL for php. I saw that whilst debugging on PhpStorm, having the `$result` on the watches list. Selecting via SQL Studio shows NULL on both fields. There's nothing special about that select statement, it's just something like `SELECT myTable.* FROM myTable Where (id = 1)`.

Comment: One more thing, because I exceeded the character limiation in my previous post: The one that is known as NULL for php is an int-Field in the table, whilst the other one that's known as an empty string is a varchar field (not an nvarchar). Everything is okay on our production system (Server A, as mentioned above in the very first post by me), where null is there on both results in php.